# How to post data to geoserver through Flask?

Tags: python, flask, geoserver-rest-pythom

I want to post .tiff raster data to geoserver programmatically through Flask without webinteface of Geoserver.Need guidance.

Comment: Use the REST api - where is it going wrong for you?

Comment: You can't post with flask because it is a web framework. You can use requests to send requests. Read the documentation and add the correct payload for files and parameters and turn the output  to a dict with json.loads. You directly return the dict with flask to a route if you want to.